# Arduino Bluetooth Module not holding connection

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I am using an HC_05 Bluetooth module and an Arduino Uno to try and set up a simple bluetooth connection with my Windows Phone (HTC 8X). I am following the online tutorial [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_communicating_with_Arduino_using_Bluetooth).

When I go into settings, my phone sees the "HC_05" bluetooth signal. I click on it, and it  connects right away. **It stays connected for 5-10 seconds, then suddenly disconnects.**

I am thinking that my phone is not receiving any data from the bluetooth module, and thus deciding that the signal is worthless, and dropping it. But even if that, why? When I call `btSerial.read()` from the linked code, isn't that talking to the device?

I'm have tried directing RX/TX directly into 0/1 on the UNO, with a voltage divider, into ports 10/11, redirecting the power to 3.3V, **all show the same problem of not holding a bluetooth connection with either my phone or computer.**

Comment: did you try setting you phone so that it never goes in sleep mode or just keeping it alive by touching the screen? If the connection is not lost this way, the problem is clearly on the phone side.

Comment: It's not that it goes into sleep mode, I literally watch it say "Connected" and then after 10 seconds of staring, and the screen not dimming, it just loses connection. The same thing happens on my computer too.

Comment: Did you try to simply power up the HC-05? (no code needed on the Arduino side) If it fails still, the problem is in the settings of the module itself.

Comment: Just tried it. `Gnd -> Gnd` and `VCC -> 3.3V`. Still connects and drops. So this means my module is a dud?

Comment: try resetting it as slave using AT commands: "AT+RESET" and  "AT+ROLE=0"

Comment: I'm having the same issue - no idea why it's failing but I can't pair it with either a laptop or a android device. Did you have any luck with it? B

Comment: Well, the same here. I can establish an connection between HC-05 and my android 4.1 device. First data arrives but afer some seconds there is no more and the connection seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

i had similar problem ..the HC 05  used to get disconnected just after 5 seconds of connection with PC but worked fine with android. But what actually worked out for me was the AccessPort .... The module remains disconnected until the Serial port is switched on in accessport. its the same case with processing ..once the sketch runs the module gets connected automatically.Make sure you add the device to your computer and note down the outgoing and incoming ports.. :) Hope this helps

link for accessport download http://www.sudt.com/en/ap/download.htm